# Porting Differential Equations from Matlab to Python 3.4 gives different results

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, scipy, differential-equations

I've been trying to port a set of differential equations from Matlab R2014b to python 3.4.

I've used both odeint and ode, with no satisfactory results. The expected results are the ones I get from Matlab where xi = xl and xj = xk with an offset of 180 in phase for each group, as you can see from the image below. [image]

The code I'm running in Matlab is the following:

```
function Fv = cpg(t, ini_i);  

freq = 2;
%fixed parameters
alpha = 5;
beta = 50;
miu = 1;
b = 1;

%initial conditions 
xi     = ini_i(1);
yi     = ini_i(2);
xj     = ini_i(3);
yj     = ini_i(4);
xk     = ini_i(5);
yk     = ini_i(6);
xl     = ini_i(7);
yl     = ini_i(8);

ri = sqrt(xi^2 + yi^2);
rj = sqrt(xj^2 + yj^2);
rk = sqrt(xk^2 + yk^2);
rl = sqrt(xl^2 + yl^2);

%frequency for all oscillators
w_swing = 1;
w_stance = freq*w_swing;

%Coupling matrix, that determines a walking gate for
%a quadruped robot. 
k = [ 0, -1, -1,  1;
     -1,  0,  1, -1;
     -1,  1,  0, -1;
      1, -1, -1,  0];

%Hopf oscillator 1
omegai = w_stance/(exp(-b*yi)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yi)+1);
xi_dot = alpha*(miu - ri^2)*xi - omegai*yi;
yi_dot = beta*(miu - ri^2)*yi + omegai*xi + k(1,2)*yj + k(1,3)*yk + k(1,4)*yl;

%Hopf oscillator 2
omegaj = w_stance/(exp(-b*yj)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yj)+1);
xj_dot = alpha*(miu - rj^2)*xj - omegaj*yj;
yj_dot = beta*(miu - rj^2)*yj + omegaj*xj + k(2,1)*yi + k(2,3)*yk + k(2,4)*yl;

%Hopf oscillator 3
omegak = w_stance/(exp(-b*yk)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yj)+1);
xk_dot = alpha*(miu - rk^2)*xk - omegak*yk;
yk_dot = beta *(miu - rk^2)*yk + omegak*xk + k(3,4)*yl + k(3,2)*yj + k(3,1)*yi;

%Hopf oscillator 4
omegal = w_stance/(exp(-b*yl)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yl)+1);
xl_dot = alpha*(miu - rl^2)*xl - omegal*yl;
yl_dot = beta *(miu - rl^2)*yl + omegal*xl + k(4,3)*yk + k(4,2)*yj + k(4,1)*yi; 

%Outputs
Fv(1,1) = xi_dot;
Fv(2,1) = yi_dot;
Fv(3,1) = xj_dot;
Fv(4,1) = yj_dot;
Fv(5,1) = xk_dot;
Fv(6,1) = yk_dot;
Fv(7,1) = xl_dot;
Fv(8,1) = yl_dot;
```

However, when I moved the code to python I get an output like this. 
[image]
In python I ran the ODE solver using the same time step as in Matlab and using solver 'dopri5', which is supposed to be equivalent to the one I'm using in Matlab, ode45. I use the same initial conditions in both cases. I've used both odeint and ode with similar results. 
I just started programming in Python and it is my first implementation using Scipy and Numpy so maybe I'm misinterpreting something?

```
def cpg(t, ini, k, freq):
    alpha = 5
    beta = 50
    miu = 1
    b = 1
    assert freq == 2

    'Initial conditions'
    xi = ini[0] 
    yi = ini[1]
    xj = ini[2]
    yj = ini[3]
    xk = ini[4]
    yk = ini[5]
    xl = ini[6]
    yl = ini[7]

    ri = sqrt(xi**2 + yi**2)
    rj = sqrt(xj**2 + yj**2)
    rk = sqrt(xk**2 + yk**2)
    rl = sqrt(xl**2 + yl**2)

    'Frequencies for each oscillator'
    w_swing = 1
    w_stance = freq * w_swing

    'First Oscillator'
    omegai = w_stance/(exp(-b*yi)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yi)+1)
    xi_dot = alpha*(miu - ri**2)*xi - omegai*yi
    yi_dot =  beta*(miu - ri**2)*yi + omegai*xi + k[1]*yj + k[2]*yk + k[3]*yl

    'Second Oscillator'
    omegaj = w_stance/(exp(-b*yj)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yj)+1)
    xj_dot = alpha*(miu - rj**2)*xj - omegaj*yj
    yj_dot =  beta*(miu - rj**2)*yj + omegaj*xj + k[4]*yi + k[6]*yk + k[7]*yl

    'Third Oscillator'
    omegak = w_stance/(exp(-b*yk)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yk)+1)
    xk_dot = alpha*(miu - rk**2)*xk - omegak*yk
    yk_dot =  beta*(miu - rk**2)*yk + omegak*xk + k[8]*yi + k[9]*yj + k[11]*yl

    'Fourth Oscillator'
    omegal = w_stance/(exp(-b*yl)+1) + w_swing/(exp(b*yl)+1)
    xl_dot = alpha*(miu - rl**2)*xl - omegal*yl
    yl_dot =  beta*(miu - rl**2)*yl + omegal*xl + k[12]*yi + k[13]*yj + k[14]*yk

    return [xi_dot, yi_dot, xj_dot, yj_dot, xk_dot, yk_dot, xl_dot, yl_dot]
```

The way that I'm calling the ODE is as follows:

```
X0 = [1,-1, 0,-1, 1,1, 0,1] 
r = ode(cpg).set_integrator('dopri5')
r.set_initial_value(X0).set_f_params(k_trot, 2)

t1 = 30.
dt = .012
while r.successful() and r.t < (t1-dt):
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
```

I hope I was clear enough. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your Python isn't self-contained, so it's hard to know if the differences between your Python and Matlab equations are intended or not.  (Aside: that much duplication is screaming out for a refactor.)

Comment: Before calling an ODE solver, compare the output of the matlab and python versions of `cpg` for the same inputs.  Try an assortment of different cases.  If `cpg` does not produce the same output in python as it does in matlab, then the results of the ODE solvers will certainly be different.

Comment: Following on @WarrenWeckesser, matlab cpg has `freq = 2` while python cpg has `freq` as an input parameter.  It presumably should always be passed as 2 (or 2.0), but adding `assert freq == 2` would make sure.

Comment: Why, in python, use `pow(x, 2)` instead of `x ** 2` or even `x * x` in both versions (that likely being the most efficient)?  My previous comment about `freq` applies to `k` also.  Is the passed in value that same as the constant (once converted to a vector)?

Comment: I would check the `k` array.  The oscillators aren't interacting.

Comment: Thanks guys! @WarrenW, @TerryJanReedy, @hpaulj I implemented all of your suggestions, apparently it was a combination of two things, the `assert freq==2` helped as well as the `k` matrix. I didn't get an indexing error for that one since in a part of the software the code was accidentally deleting a coma while exporting the `k` matrix. So I was using a k matrix with a lower index than the expected one, but I didn't get an indexing error since I wasn't using the diagonal (`k[0], k[5], k[10], k[15]`).